# Convert data into JSONP from json not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I am trying to obtain data in jsonp format so that I can work with phonegap. But on the web browser it doesn't work and there are no error showing in the console. Clearly, something must be wrong with the code, But as I have never done jsonp before If somebody could help please.
php api

```
function airportlist_get() {

    $this->load->database();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM airport order by airport;';
    $sql2 = 'SELECT COUNT(a_id) AS records FROM airport';
    $query2 = $this->db->query($sql2);
    $data2 = $query2->row();
    $info->records = intval($data2->records);
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $data = $query->result();
    $info->airports = $data;
$callback = isset($_GET['callback']) ? preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9$_]/si', '',        $_GET['callback']) : false;
    header('Content-Type: ' . ($callback ? 'application/javascript' : 'application/json') . ';charset=UTF-8');
$json = json_encode($info);
$jsonp_callback = isset($callback) ? $json: null;
    $this->response($jsonp_callback, 200);
}
```

Ajax call:

```
function Getairports(){
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/~airports/airports/v1.0/index.php/airport/airportlist',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
     $("#airportlist").empty();
        $.each(data.airports,function(i,airport){
    $('#airportlist').append('<li> <a href="#shopbyairport" data-transition="slide" onclick="Getshops('+airport.a_id+')">'+airport.airport+'</a></li>');
a_id = airport.a_id;
console.log(a_id);
});

 $.mobile.changePage("#airports"); 

 $('#airportlist').listview('refresh');
 },

 error: function (response) {
        var r = jQuery.parseJSONP(response.responseText);
        alert("Message: " +r.error.text);

    }
    }
          )};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the error log in the browser, you will see that you get a syntax error when you request the file.

The response is not valid JSONP. You have this added at the end of the response:

```
"{\"records\":2,\"airports\":[{\"a_id\":\"2\",\"airport\":\"Birmingham International\"},{\"a_id\":\"1\",\"airport\":\"Luton Airport\"}]}"
```

Comment: So how do I change that

Comment: I have changed that but that was because as I was editing after posting the file was echo the results along with the response

Comment: @user3368909: Now the response contains only that string, there is no JSONP in it at all.

Comment: Okay I will leave echo $callback . '('.$json.')'; and delete $this->response($jsonp_callback, 200);

Comment: @user3368909: That's better, but you miss the function name in the JSONP response.

Comment: @user3368909: My bad, I was requesting it without the right parameters. Now the response looks fine, and code is working. I commented out the jQUery.Mobile specific stuff and tested it: http://jsfiddle.net/8rpA4/

Comment: It does not work on website, if you click on airports it doesn't work http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/~airports/final/

Comment: @user3368909: Check the error log, you have a syntax error in ajax.js. You are missing the closing bracket on the `Getairports` function.

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP script, instead of this line:

```
$jsonp_callback = isset($callback) ? $json: null;
```

put this line:

```
$jsonp_callback = isset($callback) ? $callback . '(' . $json . ')': null;
```

It should work afterwards.